# How to fix class dependancy due to a circular import in Python?

Tags: python, class, module

I have `One` and `Two` python classes that defined like below:

```py
# one.py file
from Two import Two

class One:
    simple_one = 'one'
    complex_one = simple_one + Two.simple_two
```

```py
# two.py file
from One import One

class Two:
    simple_two = 'two'
    complex_two = simple_two + One.simple_one
```

I also have a `main.py` file:

```py
from Two import Two

print(Two.complex_two)
```

when I run `main.py` script, I get this error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Two' from partially initialized
> module 'Two' (most likely due to a circular import)

**How should i fix this error?**

Answer (score 0):

Dont circular import ?

If you would need a hammer to build a hammer and no hammer is present in the world you aren't gonna get a hammer.

Comment: This is just a nice sentence but not useful.

Comment: What can I say. You just can't circular import.

I mean you are creating infinite recursion.